# How to install a minimal Debian?

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I am looking for a minimal version of Debian, I would install something like the Dekstop Environment by myself, just like the Alpine installer. Is there some minimal installation of Debian?

Comment: Some distributions like lubuntu (lite ubuntu, debian based, tuned to run on very small machines) are probably a good starting point...

Comment: Considerably No , I am using Lubuntu right now , and I am bored up of it . I want Debian Minimal Installation , so that I would be able to install the DE which I want and I could also change my De by remove the one which is default but I don't want any bloatware in my PC

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To install a minimal Debian, use the standard installer (*e.g.* on [a network installation image](https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst)), in either graphical or text mode, and when you get to the “Software selection” phase (towards the end), deselect everything:

[image: Software selection screen with nothing selected]

This will result in a small setup with around 220 packages installed (the exact number will vary depending on the locale you chose and the detected hardware).

Answer (score 4):

Download the CD ISO, but to have WiFi access you should download the second or third ISO.

The CD ISO contains minimum packages, rest of the required packages will be installed during the installation process (if required). So, internet connection is a must.

Then during installation process untick all the desktop environments and then continue, after the installation process is done.

Login and from the terminal window install whatever window manager or DE you want to install.

[You can also use this video as a step by step guide](https://youtu.be/_FZCXVgiORA)